# How do I display image in the right column in an sql table?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am inserting values to an sql table and displaying it through AJAX. The values get displayed properly but the image does not come in the right column, instead it comes on top. Why does this happen?

Although the image is shown in the webpage, it is however aligned in different position.
[image]

```
<?php
...
...
...
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Time</th>
     <th>Img</th>
    </tr>
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Time"].'</td>
    <td>' ?> <img src="<?php echo $row['Img']; ?>" alt="my picture" height="100" width="100" /> <?php '</td>  //Here is the problem where I am trying to display the image
   </tr>
  ';

 }
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}

?>
```

Comment: Please use prepared statements. Otherwise there is a risk of sql injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: By seeing your code, I can see you started div, started table but I can not see end clause of it after tr tag.
Just close table and div tag after tr ends and before echo $output

Comment: @Rupal the line `<td>' ?> <img src="<?php echo $row['Img']; ?>" alt="my picture" height="100" width="100" /> <?php '</td>` is causing the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
 $output .= '
  <div class="table-responsive">
   <table class="table table bordered">
    <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Name</th>
     <th>Time</th>
     <th>Img</th>
    </tr>
 ';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
 {
  $output .= '
   <tr>
    <td>'.$row["ID"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Name"].'</td>
    <td>'.$row["Time"].'</td>
    <td> <img src="' .$row["Img"] . '" alt="my picture" height="100" width="100" /> </td>  //Here is the problem where I am trying to display the image
   </tr>';
 }
 $output .= '</table></div>';
 echo $output;
}
else
{
 echo 'Data Not Found';
}
```

try this way.

Comment: To elaborate a little, the cause of the problem seems to be the echo statement. The output is buffered in $output, but echo is executed immediately which places the echoed image before the other output. The problem is solved by removing "echo" and instead concatenating $row['Img'] into $output.

Comment: Thanks alot. It works well now. Yes the problem was in the echo statement.